# Looking for Advanced RegEx Replacement Formula

Tags: regex, visual-c++, notepad++

I'm wanting to do a find/replace code. I'm using NotePad++ but can use pretty much anything else if it opens possibilities.

This is what I am currently working with:

```
Asus Zenfone 4
<DeviceId>
<AndroidBoardName>EeePad
<AndroidBootloader>unknown
<DeviceBrand>asus
<DeviceModel>WW_ZenFone
<DeviceModelIdentifier>LRX21V
<DeviceModelBoot>redhookbay
<HardwareManufacturer>asus
<HardwareModel>ASUS_T00I
<FirmwareBrand>ASUS_T00I
<FirmwareTags>release-keys
<FirmwareType>user
<FirmwareFingerprint>asus/WW_ZenFone/ASUS_T00I:5.0/LRX21V/WW_ZenFone-V7.4.4-20150831:user/release-keys
```

What I am needing to accomplish is to make it look like the following:

```
Asus Zenfone 4
{
DeviceId = "",
AndroidBoardName = "EeePad",
AndroidBootloader = "unknown",
DeviceBrand = "asus",
DeviceModel = "WW_ZenFone",
DeviceModelIdentifier = "LRX21V",
DeviceModelBoot = "redhookbay",
HardwareManufacturer = "asus",
HardwareModel = "ASUS_T00I",
FirmwareBrand = "ASUS_T00I",
FirmwareTags = "release-keys",
FirmwareType = "user",
FirmwareFingerprint = "asus/WW_ZenFone/ASUS_T00I:5.0/LRX21V/WW_ZenFone-V7.4.4-20150831:user/release-keys",
},
```

I was hoping this was possible using RegEx and it's advanced find/replace methods.  Here is what I believe all needs to be done:

1. Add a line break after the Phone Name and insert a { followed by another line break
2. Find the opening < and remove it
3. Find the closing > and replace it with a [space]=[space]
4. Ignore the text between the opening and closing <>
5. Wrap quotes around the word after the closing >
6. Add a comma after the last quote
7. Add a line break and insert },

If I am in over my head, please just let me know and I'll get to doing the manual labor of just copy/pasting everything one by one.

Comment: You could do it in 2 steps or you can use a callback. Both of which might not be desireable/doable in notepad++. Using  C# it's easily done.

Comment: 2 step approach is Find `((?:<[^>]*>.*(?:\r?\n)*)+)` Replace with `{\n$1\n}` then Find `<([^>]*)>(.*)` Replace `$1="$2",` The callback approach uses step 1 then pass $1 to the callback where a string is constructed with `"{\n"` + a step 2 regex on passed in string + `"\n}"` which is then passed back.

Comment: Each of those regexes is used in a global find/replace. They can be done separately, but _Step1_ must be done first. So, in notepad, it's manual, but only 2 steps need to be done _once_ for everything and probably better if a 1-off type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do in Notepad++ using Replace with activated *Regular expression*.

You can then search for `(?:\G(?<!^)|(.+))\R<([^>]*)>(.*+)((?!\R<))?` and replace with `(?{1}$1\r\n\{:)\r\n$2 = "$3",(?{4}\r\n\},:)`.

Search pattern breakdown:

- `(?:\G(?<!^)|(.+))` - Matches the end of the previous match, if it is not the start of a line (`\G` matches the start of the string in the first run) or matches any character (except newline), one or more times and stores it into group one.
- `\R<([^>]*)>(.*+)` - Matches a newline followed by `<`, then any amount of characters that are no `>` (stored into group 2), then `>` and then any amount of characters till the end of the line (stored into group 3)
- `((?!\R<))?` - Stores an empty group 4, if the next line is not starting with `<`

Replace pattern breakdown:

- `(?{1}$1\r\n\{:)` - Conditional replace: if group 1 is present, then take the content of group 1, followed by a newline (you might want to use `\n` instead of `\r\n` depending on your systems default linebreak)
- `\r\n$2 = "$3",` - add a newline, followed by the content of group 2, then space `=` space, finally the content of group 3, surrounded by `"`
- `(?{4}\r\n\},:)` - Conditional replace: if group 4 is present, add a newline and `},`

Comment: Pretty fancy, conditional's in the replace string. A whole nother place to embed code.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing!  It worked like a charm and I couldn't ask for anything better.  How long did it take you to put this together?  I'm assuming you must have been working with RegEx for years to be able to tackle something like this as if it were child's play.  Any good sources you can point me towards for learning the best of this.  I'm glad you included the breakdown of what each section did because that is what truly helped me understand what you did and why.  :)

Comment: Glad it helped. I learnt from http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and Jeffrey Friedls book Mastering Regular Expressions. But what helped me most is definitely participating at SO and reading answers from all those brilliant guys. You can find dokumentation for the regex flavour used by Notepad++ (boost) [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html).

Comment: Feel free to [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helped.